# Утечка памяти или непонятно, куда делось 1.5Гб ОЗУ

Tags: сервер, top

Подскажите, пожалуйста. По ТОР команде видно, что занято всего метров 200, однако из 2Гб ОЗУ свободно всего 210Мб, куда делись остальные 1.5Гб ОЗУ, не могу понять. Тут на скрине видна загрузка сервера:

[image: Скрин]

Сервер выделенный, вся тачка моя. Сайт один расположен, хоть и плоховато он написан, но всё же.  Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так это нормально. Память должна использоваться.К тому же, мне кажется, что нужно суммировать значения по столбцу VIRT и сумма должна быть меньше, чем swap + phys. Еще не следует забывать про кэши различных родов (дисковый, например).

Comment: Фигово, что это нормально. Ок, спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание на значения buffers и cached. Они в сумме как раз дадут потерянное Вами. Это абсолютно нормально и ничего плохого в этом нет. Ядро видит свободную память, и чтобы той памяти не простаивать, забирает ее под буфера и кэш. На самом деле может быть ядру оно и не очень надо, но если есть свободная память, то почему бы ее не занять?

Вы вполне можете назапускать еще приложений где-нибудь на гигабайт оперативки (и даже больше). Ядро заметит это и поумерит свои аппетиты. Конечно какой-то минимум на кэш и буфера оставить надо.

Т.е. не рассматривайте текущую ситуацию, как то, что у вас осталось только 210М оперативки для Ваших приложений. Это совсем не так.

О достижении лимита оперативной памяти можно судить только по началу активного использования раздела подкачки (swap). Например у меня сейчас на ноуте свободно 60-90Мб, и что самое интересное - если я запущу еще десяток - другой приложений, эта цифра не особо изменится. Ядро автоматом оставляет определенный минимум, а все остального гребет себе.